# PowerShell script morning checks

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the below script which I run specifically against HP servers to identify if there is a disk error from the Windows event log and then send an email with either the message from the log or nothing to report. The issue is when testing the script either always says nothing to report when I know there is (if I can the source to something I can see in the logs) or it prints out a message from a completely different log.

```
foreach ($Server in $servers) { 
    $event = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName "system" -After ([DateTime]::Today)

    if ($event.Source -eq "HP Smart Array" -or $event.Source -eq "HpCISSs2" -or $event.Source -eq "disk") {  
        $body += Write-Output "Server $server has an error $($event.Message)         `n"  ForegroundColor Red
    } else {
        $body += Write-Output "Server $server has nothing to report           `n"
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$event` variable contains number of elements. You can't compare them with just `-eq` operator. You could use `.Contains()` method instead. Like so:

```
 if ($event.Source.Contains("HP Smart Array") -or $event.Source.Contains("HpCISSs2") -or $event.Source.Contains("disk"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response however that doesn't appear to have helped. I have Amended the script and changed the source to be something i know exists in my test server and it still comes back nothing to report.

Comment: foreach ($server in $servers) { 
 $event = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName "system"  -After ([DateTime]::Today)

                    if ($event.Source.Contains("DistributedCOM") -or $event.Source.Contains("HttpEvent")) {  
                        $body += Write-Output "Server $server has an error $($event.Message -split '\n')        `n"  ForegroundColor Red
 
                            } else { 
    $body += Write-Output "Server $server has nothing to report           `n"
 
                            }

Comment: @richb What PowerShell version are you running (`$PSVersionTable`)?

Comment: @richb Can't reproduce. Note, however, that the described approach only works for exact matches, not partial matches. For the latter you'd need something like `$event.Source -like "*HP Smart Array*"`.

Comment: Ok thanks, i copied and pasted the source names so they are exact matches or at least should be.

Answer (score -1):

Add another 'foreach' for events:

```
foreach ($Server in $servers) {
    $events = Get-Eventlog .......
    foreach ($event in $events) {
        if ($event.Source ......
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vadim, the issue with another for each statement is it goes through every event from today and writes-ouput - nothing to report for every log. Which means with lots of servers it becomes unreadable.

Comment: Remove 'else' block. To divide servers add some header like 'write-host $server' before '$events = Get-Eventlog .......'